# Vlookup with todays date in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to use the current date as a lookup reference value in pandas/python? I have tried to adapt the `pd.merge` method but that seems to want to read and merge from 2 datasets whereas I only have one.

As an example, I am wanting to match the current date to the values in the below dataset so that I can then write them to to a separate file.

**NB**: I'm only looking for help with the lookup part as I'm trying to work through the rest of the script myself.

| Date | Main | Dessert | Menu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18/04/2021 | Sunday Roast | Ice Cream | a |
| 19/04/2021 | Mac & Cheese | Fruit Yoghurt | 1 |
| 20/04/2021 | Sausage & Roast Potatoes | Coconut Sponge | 1 |

Code I have so far testing the `pd.merge` method;

```
import csv 
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
df1 = {today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}
df2 = pd.read_csv('/home/***/schoolmeals/summermeals.csv')
  

inner_join = pd.merge(df2, 
                      df1, 
                      on ='Date', 
                      how ='inner')
inner_join

print(inner_join)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I'd just use `loc` to find today's values, and you can use `pd.to_datetime('today')` as your comparison value:

```
>>> df2.loc[pd.to_datetime(df2.Date) == pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]

          Date           Main     Dessert Menu
0  18/04/2021   Sunday Roast   Ice Cream     a
```